# Can MS Outlook 2007 print the entire day's schedule, in the weekly calendar view?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I like printing my schedule in the weekly calendar view, which shows all the hours of the day, rather than the list view.  My problem is that I can't get it to print the entire day's appointments - everything entered after 7:00 pm doesn't show up on my printed schedule.  Does anyone know how to correct this?  I would help me so much!

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your printer's drivers, but you can check this: When you print, you may be able to change the page setup, and in that, pick the hours you want to print. Look at the following screenshot. If you have to, save it to your computer so you can open it with an image application to make it larger for easier viewing. I clicked "print", and that is the left box, and clicked "page setup", and that is the right box.

[image]